# Implementación hora y fecha en Django

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Hola estoy implementando la hora y fecha cuando se crea un registro pero, sucede que cuando se crea el primero la hora queda pegada y los siguientes registros se guardar con la hora del primero siempre.

Configuración del settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-co'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Bogota'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
```

El Modelo

```
class Registro(models.Model):
    """Modelo para registrar_visita usuario"""
    day  = timezone.now()
    hour = timezone.now()
    #formatedHour = hour.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    formatedDay  = day.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
    formatedHour = hour.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    nombre_usuario = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, blank=True,    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cliente = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dia = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=formatedDay)
    hora_marca = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=formatedHour) 
    latitud = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    longitud = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
          template = '{0.id}, {0.nombre_usuario}, {0.cliente}, {0.dia}, {0.hora_marca}, {0.latitud}, {0.longitud}'
          return template.format(self)
```

Por ultimo donde recibo los datos en la API

```
class RegistroCreate(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = RegistroUsuarioSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: No sé si puedes explicar un poco más detallado el problema, porque no logro entender que sucede, si puedes poner ejemplos mucho mejor

Comment: @GermanAlzate Mira yo envio estos datos a la API `{"cliente":"Surtimax","latitud":"4.7405617","longitud":"-74.0298981","nombre_usuario":"Julian","usuario":1}` Al crear ese registro yo debo guardar la fecha dia y la Hora especifica en la que se creo, como vez en el modelo yo realizo eso, pero sucede que si yo sigo realizando nuevos registros la hora sigue siendo la misma siempre con cualquier nuevo registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno pude resolver mi problema con lo siguiente:

```
  def get_default_my_hour():
      hour = timezone.now()
      formatedHour = hour.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
      return formatedHour


  Class Registro(models.Model):
      """Modelo para registrar_visita usuario"""
      day  = timezone.now()
      formatedDay  = day.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

      nombre_usuario = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, null=True, blank=True,      on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      cliente = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      dia = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=formatedDay)
      hora_marca = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=get_default_my_hour) 
      latitud = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      longitud = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que cada que le das al comando `./manage.py runserver` en tu clase le estás diciendo a Django que guarde el valor en string de la fecha actual en la variable `formatedDay` y `formatedHour` al hacerlo de esa forma que lo haces solamente es llamar la fecha una vez, y django lo almacena así en la RAM, con ese valor inicial.

La forma de trabajar con `Timestamps` o `Estampas de Tiempo` django te la proporciona en su campo de fecha, y puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
class Registro(models.Model):
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

De esta forma, dejas que django se encargue de agregar la fecha cada vez que se crea un nuevo objeto de esa clase, y ya tienes incluida la fecha y la hora

Comment: Debe ser eso lo que sucede, pero no era la solución que estaba buscando.